# Displaying infinite Items in a Listbox control (XAML Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am making an E-Shopping app for Windows Phone platform. I'm stuck at a place where I need to display all the Search result Found after user input has been recorded. The issue arising is that ,  only the Products of the 1st Search Result page(as in the Website) get displayed. I need to load and display all the Products of the search term.

**You can check the XAML CODE I'm using in the following link,** and please tell what I need to add in it to display ALL the results instead of being limited to 1 page only.

***http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a85be6c-5e46-4815-8163-931d1584e363/load-infinite-items-in-a-listbox?forum=wpdevelop***

Answer (score 0):

You should use LongListSelector as ListBox depreciated.

[Here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx) is an explanation of How to create Infinite Scroll in a LongListSelector.

Basically you will be adding a definite number of items in LongListSelector as the user scrolls down to the end of the list.

Comment: @Vaibhav Try using LongListSelector. If you face any issue then post another que. No One will right the whole code for you, you are gonna have to try first.

Comment: I just tried using LongListSelector control also , but still no success. The results are still limited to just 1 page after scroll, and furthur doesnt scroll. It 'd be really nice if you can give its implementation in detail, by suggesting the Edits I should do in that Xaml cODE that I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your xml/json response that the items on the Page 2 is downloaded to your app? I think you are missing out some params in your web api call.

Because In general, a web api call doesnot provide all items at once, only we have to fetch in some pattern continiously.

Comment: The json response ie. the web api call I implemented is absolutely fine, all the relevant data is ther, but in Listbox only Page 1 items are getting displayed. The basic issue is "Detecting the end of Listbox and load more data on scroll". I got  a few ways to do so but not working for me, as all the samples show to implement it with "Dummy items" , and in my case, a dynamic object call is there. Please suggest me an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using LongListSelector ItemRealized Event. Here is a detailed sample, I checked its perfectly working

http://www.damirscorner.com/InfiniteScrollingWithIncrementalLoadingInWindowsPhone8.aspx